# Adding a colon to language in K

Tags: kframework

How do I add colon as a syntactic construct in my language? I've added it to the syntax, but when I try to match a colon inside a rule it gives me a parse error.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add more context? Possibly an example code snippet that includes the syntax and the rule declarations? Thanks!

Comment: I unfortunately don't remember what my exact syntax was.

Answer (score 0):

K is getting confused when you surround it with parenthesis.  Delete the surrounding parenthesis and the parse error should be removed.